# Getting Started with Python on Heroku

Tags: python, heroku

I am going through this tutorial for Flask: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python#specify-dependencies-with-pip

When I get to [the part](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python#procfile) where I execute: 'foreman start'
I receive: 'foreman is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.'

Could I please get some help in remedying this?

Thanks!

Also, I am running windows 7.

Comment: Is there a file named foreman or similar in python_install_dir\Scripts?

Comment: According to the [Heroku Dev Center](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile#developing-locally-with-foreman), `foreman` is automatically installed by the Heroku Toolbelt. Did you install that?

Comment: 2rs2ts is right, the installer should set the path. Create a new terminal window (instead of using one that was open before you ran the installer, so that the new path is then used.

Comment: You don't need foreman to push to Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

Old issue, but I ran into the same problem.

Needed to run: `gem install foreman`